# Problema $_REQUEST

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando agregar un nuevo usuario mediante un formulario a partir de los input type name y luego lo paso para que se creen en la tabla1 de la base de datos jardineri, pero no sé porqué no me comprende los request.
Os pongo el código y también el resultado que me da:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="es-ES"> 
<head> 
     <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
      <title>Inserción</title>

<style>
    h2 {text-align:center;}
    table { background-color:#E9FFFF;margin:auto; 
            border:1px solid red; border-collapse:collapse;}
    td { border: 1px solid red;}
    td.centrados {text-align:center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?
if($_REQUEST)
{
$conexion=mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","dbpracticas") or die ("No se puede  conectar"); 
$nombrebd="dbpracticas";
$nombretabla="tabla1";
mysqli_select_db ($conexion,$nombrebd) or die ("No se puede selecionar la bd $nombretabla");
/*$nif=$_REQUEST['nif']; 
$nombre=$_REQUEST['nombre'];
$apellido1=$_REQUEST['apellido1'];
$apellido2=$_REQUEST['apellido2'];
$fecha_nac=$_REQUEST['fecha_nac'];
$sexo=$_REQUEST['sexo'];*/
/*Equivalente*/
extract($_REQUEST);

    $insertar="INSERT INTO $nombretabla  (nif,nombre,apellido1,apellido2,fechanaci,sexo)VALUES ('$nif','$nombre','$apellido1','$apellido2','$fecha_nac','$sexo')";
    if (mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar))
    {   
    echo "Se ha realizado con éxito la inserción";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error en inserción";
         }

# cerramos la conexion

 mysqli_close($conexion); 
}
?>
<h1>FORMULARIO</h1>
<form action="insertarcompleto.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>NIF</td><td><input type="text" name="nif" size=9 pattern="[0-9]{8}[A-Za-z]"></td></tr>
<tr><td>NOMBRE</td><td><input type="text" name="nombre"></td></tr>
<tr><td>APELLIDO1</td><td><input type="text" name="apellido1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>APELLIDO2</td><td><input type="text" name="apellido2"></td></tr>
<tr><td>FECHA NACIMIENTO</td><td><input type="date" name="fecha_nac"></td></tr>
<tr><td>SEXO</td><td><select NAME="sexo">
        <option>V</option>
        <option>M</option>
    </select></td></tr>
    <tr> 
<td class="centrados" colspan='2'><input type=submit value="Enviar">
<input type=reset value="Borrar"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Sé que el resultado parece un formulario sin rellenar, pero eso es lo que sale, en vez de poner la línea de si se cumple la instrucción, me ponga que se ha realizado con éxito y si es lo contrario que no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes comentado el código que saca los datos del `$_REQUEST`, así no va a tomar los datos en las variables.

Comment: Podría ser que no tengas activada la opción short_open_tag https://www.php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag Por otra parte, no es buena idea incluir entradas de datos directamente en consultas, sin validar y sin escapar, tu sistema será vulnerable a todo tipo de ataques.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, pero eso está comentado porque se supone que el extract($_REQUEST) debería de coger todos los valores.

Comment: @ihenryy93 revertí tu edición, amigo la solución no va en la pregunta sino en la zona de respuestas